# How do I prevent WIFI from being disabled in Windows 10 Safe Mode w/ Networking?

Tags: windows-10, wifi-driver, safe-mode

We have a project going that requires a program be run in Safe Mode as admin.  Everyone is working from home and home users mostly do not have Ethernet.  They are also not local admins.  We need to remote into the computer to run a command that takes 5 seconds.

Is there a registry change we can make to keep the WIFI driver from getting disabled when going into Safe Mode?

Is there some way through policy we can allow standard users to enable the device without making them local admins (not even temporary)?

Comment: Did you try starting in Safe Mode WITH Networking? That should work.

Comment: Yes.  Ethernet is working in the rare case a home user has a cable for it.  When the user gets to the login screen it shows airplane mode but if you go to device manager the device driver is disabled.  Standard users cannot enable device drivers by default.

Comment: Sounds like a case for virtualization and a VM.  If the user cannot enable a device due their permissions then you have a problem a non privileged user cannot solve

Comment: We are trying to remove an anti-virus application from all workstations but Covid work from home is not playing nice with necessary admin tasks.  The removal code is not working for 80 of 160 machines which is why we need to go into safe mode.  It's a complete PITA.